# Why can I see only five posts in the top posts section on the Stack Overflow mobile app?

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

Under the user profile screen in mobile app, I can see only five posts in the *top posts* section, and it doesn't allow to scroll down to see more posts.

If it's a correct one, then the header text should be *top 5 posts* instead of *top posts*.

**Android Version:** 7.0

**Device:** Huawei Honor 8

Click [here](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_honor_8-8195.php) for more information about the device.

Comment: Again, use some ___proper tags___ in your questions. What app are you using?

Comment: Why always you are saying tag properly? **HMMM!** :( **Reason for bug tag** : `I can seeing only 5 posts in top posts section`, **reason for feature-request tag**: `If it's a correct one, then the header text should be top 5 posts instead of top posts`

Comment: That's not a feature request. That's a small correction. And you're missing a bunch of tags.

Comment: Another point, when you post regarding app there is android and ios.. you need to specifiy the platform (and tag it) and the version you have installed is also helpful

Comment: @RameshRajendran: ___Every single question___ you submitted on meta the past few days was of low quality. Poorly tagged, every single one of them only tagged with bug, FR or discussion.

Comment: I was talking about the SO app version in the previous comment. And mobile model doesnt seem relevant here

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be consistent across both mobile apps - both the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow app only show five top posts in a user's profile.  There's no way to expand the list.

That said, no behavior is broken, so this isn't a bug.

Apologies for the screenshot size; I'm on mobile and can't crop them.

Here's Stack Overflow.

> [image]

And here's Stack Exchange.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

This is the same as the website. In the (iOS) app, you can click *"all x posts"* to see the full list:

> [image]

Comment: But  I am not able to see `all x posts` button anywhere in the user profile screen.

Comment: The button is there in the iOS app. If you don't tell us what you're using, we can't help you.

Comment: I have updated my question for which phone am using

Comment: @RameshRajendran Post a screenshot of your phone.